# How does Sagecrafting work?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

When considering creating a character with a high level of Sagecraft, I wanted to know what the potential gain was.

Clearly shards are used to create gems that can be added to equipment, but how does one go from collecting shards to gaining useful bonuses?

What kinds of shards exist?  Are there different quality levels?  What sorts of bonuses do they give?  Can different types of shards be combined to create unusual gems (like cubing for a prismatic amulet in Diablo II)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shards effectively have quality levels. Instead of adding more ingredients like Alchemy and Blacksmithing, increasing one's Sagecrafting skill allows for the use of more advanced shards.

**Sagecraft by the Numbers**

*Three quality levels:*

- Cloudy
- Lambent
- Pristine

*Seven shard types:*

- Fire
- Ice
- Lightning
- Magic
- Physical
- Poison
- Protection

*Four gem categories:*

- Weapon
- Armor
- Utility
- Epic

**Skill Progression**

All characters can combine *Cloudy Shards* into gems innately. At **level 2**, you can combine *Lambent Shards* into gems. At **level 6**, you can use *Pristine Shards*.

Reaching **level 3** in Sagecrafting lets you fuse identical shards into a higher tier, much like Diablo II's Horadric Cube, or Torchlight's Transmuter.

Reaching **level 8** unlocks the *epic gems* recipe category.

Reaching **Level 10** allows a master Sagecrafter to extract gems from equipment, with no harm to either gem or armament.

Every time you increase your Sagecrafting skill you also increase the chance of finding shards in the first place.

**Gem Recipes**

Like Alchemy, there are set combinations to create certain effects. *Unlike* Alchemy, you get a preview of the results of the transmutation before performing it, so you're never sagecrafting blindly.

There are 196 different combinations (7 shard types, 2 shards per gem, 4 categories), but there is some overlap; For instance, Fire + Protection and Ice + Protection both give + Physical Damage when used as a weapon gem.